# How can I draw a 2D circular plot?

Tags: plotting

I have a function $Q(y)$, which I would like to plot this radially using varying color shades to show the variation in the function. I'm looking for a 2D surface plot, maybe like `DensityPlot`, but circular and versus one parameter ($y$). An example use case would be plotting the angular velocity of a galaxy with color, assuming that it is radially symmetric.

You can assume an arbitrary $Q(y)$, e.g. $1/y^2$. Now for each $y$, we have a value for $Q(y)$. One way to show the results is to plot $Q(y)$ vs. $y$. But I would prefer if I can have a circular plot where for each $y$ there is a ring where $y$ is constant. I would like the color of this ring to be determined by the value of $Q(y)$.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `PolarPlot`?

Comment: If `PolarPlot` isn't what you're looking for, do you have an example of what kind of plot you're trying to make?

Comment: I'm looking for a 2D surface plot. Maybe kind of DensityPlot. But circular and versus one parameter. Imagine that you want to show the angular velocity of a galaxy, at each radius. In fact, each ring in this figure, supposed to show a value for the angular velocity.

Comment: you should edit the question with clarifying details, don't put in comments.  If I understand i think you should be looking at `Plot3D` with `RegionFunction` specifying a circle.

Comment: Actually no. I think the question is clear! I want a 2D region (not 3D), and a figure that for each y, shows a colored ring. the composition of all these rings will be a disk

Comment: Can you present an example of such a plot? I'm sure that would clear up our confusion if it can be provided. Why not just use `DensityPlot` but correlate it down to a radial dimension, e.g. `f[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]]`?

Comment: Dear  eyorble, actually, I have a function of "y" as Q(y). Every function that you think (for simplicity). Now for each y, we have a value for Q. One way to show the results is to plot Q vs. y. But I want another type. It would be better if I can have a circular plot, where for each y, has a ring (y=constant in polar coordinate). Also, the value of Q in this y can be seen from the intensity of its color. So hard to say :((

Comment: So what about `DensityPlot[Q[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]`, assuming that $0 \le r \le 5$ is an appropriate range for your plot?

Comment: Thank you so much  eyorble. It is the answer :)

Comment: @Ak68 I attempted to clarify your question so that it may be reopened and answered properly. Please feel free to edit it further if you feel that I have misrepresented it.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for somthing like this: `f = r \[Function] 1/2 (1 + Sin[5 Pi r]);
ParametricPlot[ r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, -Pi, Pi},
 ColorFunction -> {{x, y, r, t} \[Function] 
    ColorData["SunsetColors"][f[r]]},
 Background -> Black
 ]`

Comment: Henrik Schumacher Wo0Ow...thats it

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Since you got it right, it would be good if you would post it as an answer so that the question does not formally stay unanswered. I'll give you a +1 if you do it :)

Comment: @C.E. Thanks for pinging me. The question was closed at that time, so I could only leave a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to me from the comments that you a looking for this:

```
f = r \[Function] 1/2 (1 + Sin[5 Pi r]); 
ParametricPlot[ r {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {r, 0, 1}, {t, -Pi, Pi},
 ColorFunction -> {{x, y, r, t} \[Function] ColorData["SunsetColors"][f[r]]}, 
 Background -> Black 
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`DensityPlot` can also be used for this by substituting the appropriate expression for radius into the function's argument. For example, assuming that $0 \le r \le 5$ is an appropriate range to plot your function over, you can input:

```
DensityPlot[Q[Sqrt[x^2+y^2]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

You can borrow the `ColorFunction` and `Background` from Henrik Schumacher's answer if you prefer, as well.